# jQuery toggleClass() doesn't work in browser but works fine in fiddle

Tags: jquery, html, css

My simple 1 line of code to toggle isn't working for some reason. Below is the code. Please advise.

Strangely enough when i tried running my code in jsfiddle.net it worked just fine when i added `!important`

to my `.highlightedbutton` class but it still doesn't work on the two browsers i tried - Chrome and Safari.
Based on recommendation by Rory, I got rid of the onload attribute and made it a $(document).ready() event. Nothing seems to be working in the hover still.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <title> Jquery Project - Code Player </title>
    
    <script type = "text/javascript" src ="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"> </script>
    
    <link href="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" rel ="stylesheet">
    
    <script src = "jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"> </script>
    
    <style type="text/css">
        
        h3, html, body {
            font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
        
        #header-bar {
            width:100%;
            height:50px;
            background-color:#EDEDED;
        }
        
        h3 {
            padding:14px 400px 0px 5px;
            float:left;
        }
        
        .button {
            
            width:100px;
            background-color:#EDEDED;
            margin:10px 0;
            border: 1px solid black;
            color:black;
            padding:5px;
            display:inline-block;
            text-align:center;
            text-decoration:none;
            font-size:12px;
            float:left;
            border-radius:5px;
        }
        
        
        .highlightedButton {
            background-color:red !important;  
        }
        
        .activeButton {
            background-color:#F5FEFE;
        }
        
    </style>
         
</head>

<body> 
    
    <div id ="header-bar">
        
        <h3> CodePlayer </h3>
        
        <div class ="button-group">
            
            <button id ="html" class ="button"> HTML </button>
            <button id ="css" class ="button"> CSS </button>
            <button id ="js" class ="button"> JavaScript </button>
            <button id ="output" class ="button"> Output </button>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id ="panel">
            <textarea id ="contentHTML"></textarea>
       
    
    </div>
    
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            
            $("#html").addClass("activeButton");
            
        });
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            
            $(".button").hover(function() {

                $(this).toggleClass("highlightedbutton");

            });
        });
          
    </script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code works fine in the snippet. Check the console in your local version for errors. Also note that you should be using a document.ready event handler, not an `onload` attribute on your `body` tag

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no errors in the console. See screenshot here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ckavi7vtYG2kKcr0TYZ4_xjRDuk3ijZQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately we can't debug a problem that's not reproduceable.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if it helps maybe you can try running this code in a code editor and then opening file in a browser to reproduce the problem. I know too much work on your side but this one seems to be a head scratcher.

Comment: The output would be identical to what's in the snippet above. If it's not working for you then there's a difference on your local version which you've not recreated here

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I’ll now edit and use document.ready handler instead of onload and see if I can solve this anomaly. Out of curiousity, what are the advantages of one over another ? Why did you suggest this ?

Comment: Because any `onX` attribute is outdated and now considered bad practice. You should be using [`unobtrusive event handlers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to maintain the separation between HTML and JS. In jQuery you do that with event handlers, such as you use with `hover()`. When adding content on load you use a [`document.ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan. It works now. I followed your suggestion.

Comment: Glad it helped. I'd suggest deleting this question if that was the problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan As i tried to do that, i got a pop up saying since this has been answered once, they won't recommend deleting the question.

Comment: Try it now. It should be possible